# Is it possible to use the Debugger on Julia code called from Python or Java?

Tags: java, python, debugging, jvm, julia

The Julia Debugger is excellent, but I am working in a company that is mostly Python or Java.  I want to write the core algorithms in Julia and package them to be called by the product.

If something goes wrong, can I use the Debugger?